# Rails 4 - set session variable so user can see pages only during that session

Tags: session, ruby-on-rails-4, session-variables

I am using rails 4 and want to give an instant quote that has some personal information. I need to make the quote viewable for someone's entire session WITHOUT having them log in but someone else session could not see that quote. The idea is that they can see the quote I give them and download that quote as a PDF. Here is the essence of what I have in my controller - but it is not working.

```
class ClientsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :check_guest, :only => :show
def check_guest
  # # if user isn't logged in
  if current_user.nil? 
  #   # if user has already viewed, redirect
  #   if session[:viewed] == true
  #     flash[:alert] = "You can only view a quote once. Please resubmit your information."
  #     redirect_to root_path
  #   # if user hasn't viewed, allow access, but flag as having viewed
  #   else
  #     session[:viewed] = true
  #   end
    if session[:quote_id] == params[:id] # where params[:id] is the quote ID
      flash[:alert] = "Allow"
    else
      flash[:alert] = "Dont Allow"
    end        
  end
end
```

I imagine I need to set variable session[:quote_id] = @client.id but am not sure if I do that in the create action or the show action. Either place I put it, the entire code is not working. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Two things I needed to do.

First, set the session variable as the LAST action in create.

```
def create
....some actions
session[:quote_id] = @client.id
end
```

Next, I had to convert the params ID into an integer, so it would evaluate correctly.

```
session[:quote_id] == (params[:id].to_i)
```